# Spring boot Pageable - dynamic nativeQuery . Sort filter not working. (property not converted to column name)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT id AS USER_ID, name AS NAME FROM USERS ORDER BY ?#{#pageable} ",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(id) FROM USERS ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}

/users --> give me 20 records
/users?sort=name,desc --> give me 20 records sorted by name
/users?sort=userId,desc --> throws the error USERID not valid identifier
```

**I don't know why userId is not converted to USER_ID in nativeQuery**

Comment: **/users --> give me 20 records**
Because Pageable default size is 20, you can customize add by creating Pageable request.

Comment: Check the 3rd one which gives the error, first 2 are working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

you defined in your @Query nativeQuery = true. So in this case property not converted to column name. same goes with the entity, you have to name the table name exactly like in the query USERS rather than User entity (as you defined the native query).

try using /users?sort=USER_ID,desc 
or /users?sort=user_Id,desc

either will work.

Comment: also the default pageable size is 20, you can customize it as the kj007 mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Can you help me , i mean what i should do or add in my application such that user_id automatically is converted to userId .

Comment: did you try query without native query (entity manager query)? 

if yes and its not working then for native query your column name must match with the name in query. 
So depending upon your flow you can map it accordingly.


One approach is to send the key and value as params in findAll like 
Page<User> findAll(String searchKey, String searchTerm, Pageable pageable);
and map it accordingly in query.


There must be other effective ways in order to achieve that. I am sure it should work with entity manager query.

Comment: 1. Without nativeQuery it is working fine , but for my Native Query it does not work .
2. I am currently using JPA Repository , so entity Manager one i am not using .
3. basically problem is sorting as per the column passed which i am not able to do .